# how to replace fragments on tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tablayout

I have an activity with 2 tabs. What im trying to do is to replace between 2 fragments when each tab is pressesd. I also have 2 fragments: fragmentOne and fragmentTwo.When tab one is pressed i want to show fragmentOne and when tab two is pressed i want to show fragmentTwo. 
I'm not sure if i should create a container layout in the activity and there add the fragmentOne and fragmentTwo, or maybe there is another other way to do it?

**here is my code**

```
    public class InboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Fragment fragment;
            int position = tab.getPosition();
            //requests = position - 0
            //invitations = position - 1
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                     break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

when case is 0 i want to show fragmentOne

when case i 1 i want to show fragmentTwo

How should i do that?

Comment: use tab layout with viewpager
Follow this tutorial: https://android.jlelse.eu/tablayout-and-viewpager-in-your-android-app-738b8840c38a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

```
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
        fragment = new FirstFragment();
        break;

        case 1:
        fragment = new SecondFragment();
        break;      
    }

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/tablayout-example-android-studio.html) for more information

Comment: the tutorial really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewPager` instead.

Set an adapter in the view pager and use it with a `TabLayout` using

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```